# PHP and Secure File Manipulation / File Disclosure Vulnerabilities - How to address?

Tags: php, file, security

We have an in-house application running PHP that creates / moves and modifies local text files. We've recently deployed Checkmarx scanner to the code base and almost every file operation we execute via PHP comes back with either a file manipulation or file disclosure vulnerability with no real explanation of what the vulnerability is and how to handle it in code. A sample of this would be something like:

The scanner reports the following:

> File Manipulation
>   Query Path:
>   PHP\Cx\PHP High Risk\File Manipulation Version:0
>   Categories
>   PCI DSS v3.1: PCI DSS (3.1) - 6.5.8 - Improper access control
>   ....
>   7.  $files = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'file', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
>   FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW | FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH);
>   ....
>   37.      mkdir(dirname($repo_loc), 0755, true);

Where `INPUT_POST` and the function `dirname()` are the culprits (one example of many)

All our `$_POST` data is filtered and some of it is used eventually in file names / paths for the files to be manipulated.

Is there a secure way to handle file operations with `$_POST` data in PHP that I should be implementing, or a project that exists (ie class / module) I can use call upon to handle file operations securely? I understand the risks and to some degree why our scanner is tagging these as high vulnerabilities - I've just never had to do anything with securing PHP file operations.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you have `directory listing` enabled and with this instruction `mkdir(dirname($repo_loc), 0755, true);` you can reach to that folder via browser and maybe download the files...you can start checking that!

Comment: This is probably a better question for Software Engineering

Comment: I'm not familiar with Checkmarx but I'm guessing the issue with `mkdir()` is that you're using `0755`. It's not necessarily a problem but it is a code smell.

Comment: Just FYI, static analyzers like Checkmarx will give you *a lot* of false-positive warnings. I mean, they might even spit out a warning for every line containing `_POST`. Not saying you should ignore all of it, and there's not enough info to tell whether this is the case here, but have it in mind ... Static analyzers don't work well on dynamic languages like PHP.